# How are the number of digits in float to string conversion determined?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, number-formatting

I have a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/coder0xff/QPFloat/issues/7) requesting that rounding errors be truncated during conversion from a floating point value to a string. An excerpt:

```
System.Quadruple quad = 5.099;
Console.WriteLine(quad);
```

outputs:

```
5.099000000000000198951966012828052
```

I could guess at a naive implementation, but I assume there's some agreed upon way of deciding how many digits should be displayed. What's the algorithm? [The code in question](https://github.com/coder0xff/QPFloat/blob/7bb2c1cf81a87cd29ac2818ede7e0d5d352d35bc/QPFloat/ManagedQuadruple.cpp#L352).

Comment: It is up to the library, it [likes 34](https://github.com/coder0xff/QPFloat/blob/7bb2c1cf81a87cd29ac2818ede7e0d5d352d35bc/QPFloat/ManagedQuadruple.cpp#L390).  For a good reason, quad precision provides up to log10(2^112) = 34 decimal digits.  The noise digits are the normal outcome of converting a decimal double value to base 2, never more accurate than log10(2^53) = 16 digits.  Surely the author will ignore your bug report, he's doing it right.

Comment: Have you looked at [standard-numeric-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [custom-numeric-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)? It sounds like you may need to implement the `String^ Quadruple::ToString( String^ format, IFormatProvider^ provider )` method(s) if you want to enable changing the formatting.

Comment: According to the `System.Double.ToString` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_ToString), *"The ToString() method formats a Double value in the default ("G", or general) format of the current culture."*, so I guess it should also depend on the current culture of the environment.

Comment: You can also look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,de581d5a1a6b2a1a), for `Double.ToString`, but it's not very helpful since it's mostly calling extern methods. The comments above the [internal class Number](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs) may be useful, though.

Comment: @Brent: Not to take anything away from the question, just pointing out that you have a (presumably) double to quadruple conversion going on in the first line and most of the digits your decimal instincts would want to truncate might actually "belong there" (as being the closest a double could come to 5.099 "accurate to ~17 digits", subsequently promoted to a quad "accurate to ~34 digits").  I'm not sure there's anything meaningful to be fixed in your example since the last ~17 digits cannot be significant.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm the author of this library. The bug report is another person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brent: My comment above may be (part of) your answer (I read the issue as an afterthought - apologies).  csprogrammer001's problem is that (s)he hasn't appreciated the implications of promotion from double to quad.  Between double 5.099(...~12digits...)0 and double 5.099(...~12digits...)1 lie another ~999...9 (17 decimal 9s) valid quad values.

To get closer they should be doing something like Quad.Parse("5.09900000000000000000000000000000") or explicitly truncating your string to match their significant digits.

If plugging the double value into the quad (unassigned bits zero) gives near-as-dammit 5.09900000000000019895196601282(8052) then that is what you should render (at least 30 decimal digits based on .Net's default of 15).  The only thing you could contemplate to "fix" the example would be to "guess intention" with something like double->round->string->pad->quad and you do NOT want to be doing that.

Formatting options for your ToString() would be a nice addition.